# Javascript - trying to stop loop at certain iteration and display number of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, momentjs

I have this array of elements that are different for each day using moment.js( 4 days in total).

What i am trying to do is to display the number of elements depending on the day. The day selection is made with an arrow day switcher(next day, previous day)
In day 1 i have 3 elements (events). 3 days ago, i have 2 events etc..

i tried to make a loop that goes through the array and if the time of the events is equal with the current moment => display number of elements. But the loop doesn't stop when I want him too.

Here is the code for better understanding:

```
const m = moment();

  var ctrl = this;

  
  var DEMO_EVENTS = [
    { value: 100, time: moment() },
    { value: 155, time: moment() },
    { value: 83, time: moment() },

    { value: 211, time: moment().subtract(1, 'day') },
    { value: 138, time: moment().subtract(1, 'day') },
    { value: 55, time: moment().subtract(1, 'day') },

    { value: 183, time: moment().subtract(2, 'day') },
    { value: 103, time: moment().subtract(2, 'day') },

    { value: 98, time: moment().subtract(3, 'day') }
  ];

  var demoNumberEvents;
  var index =0;
  
// i add my AngularJS controller logic here
ctrl.date = m.format("ddd, MMM Do YY");
ctrl.demoNumberEvents = demoNumberEvents;



$scope.eventsNumber = function() { 
  
  for(index;index < DEMO_EVENTS.length;index++)
  {
    ctrl.DEMO_EVENTS = DEMO_EVENTS[index];
    if(index = m) 
    {
      break
     
    };
    if (index = m.subtract(2, 'day')) 
    {
      ctrl.demoNumberEvents = 1; 
    }
  }

  
}
```

any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Comparisons use `==` or `===`

Comment: index is a number whereas m is an object. Did you mean `DEMO_EVENTS[index].time === m` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use comparisons you need to use == or ===

For example, using your code `if (index = m.subtract(2, 'day'))` should be `if (index = m.subtract(2, 'day'))`

If you're not sure when to use == over ===, to quote Douglas Crockford's excellent JavaScript: [The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742):

```
'' == '0'           // false
0 == ''             // true
0 == '0'            // true

false == 'false'    // false
false == '0'        // true

false == undefined  // false
false == null       // false
null == undefined   // true

' \t\r\n ' == 0     // true
```

Comment: okay so i did that and moved the function to when the previous day is selected. Looped through the array and check if moment == event from the array.time. But still dosent work